# Disable an event and again enable the event back in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io, jquery-events

I would like to show **user is typing** in my chat system, whenever the user is typing. I did it by `keypress` event:

```
$('#m').keypress(function(){
  socket.emit('typing', 'user is typing...');
});
```

However I don't want it emit a `keypress` event every time any key is pressed. So whenever a key is press, emit `keypress` event, but then disable the `keypress` event for 3 seconds, so that no more **user is typing** message is passed. And again wait for 3 seconds if no key is pressed than show the user is **idle**. This is the code so far:

index.html:

```
var typing;
typing = $('#m').on('keypress',function(){

  $('#m').unbind('keypress');

  var timeout;

  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      socket.emit('typing', 'user is typing');
      setTimeout(function(){
        socket.emit('typing', 'idle');
      }, 3000);
    }, 3000);
  $('#m').bind('keypress');
});
```

It does show the **user is typing** after 3 seconds, and again after 3 second show that the user is **idle**. But if I press any key, it does not show the **user is typing** any more. I would really be grateful if you could help me solve this.

Comment: `$('#m').bind('keypress');` is missing handler function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
var disableKeyPress = false;

var typing = $('#m').on('keypress', function() {
  if (!disableKeyPress) {
    disableKeyPress = true;
    socket.emit('typing', 'user is typing');

    setTimeout(function() {
      disableKeyPress = false;

      setTimeout(function() {
        if (!disableKeyPress) {
          socket.emit('typing', 'idle');
        }
      }, 3000);
    }, 3000);
  }
});
```

Comment: perfect! Working. Thank you.]

Comment: Glad if I could help you!